# How does this TransformedDistribution compare to the Normal distribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I am working with the following TransformedDistribution:

```
Dist = TransformedDistribution[2 v S1 + 2 v S2 - v c, {S1 \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[1/2 (c + t), p], S2 \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[1/2 (c - t), 1 - p]}]
```

This random variable has neat expressions for mean, variance, skewness, and kurtosis:

```
(-1 + 2 p) t v

-4 c (-1 + p) p v^2

((1 - 2 p) t v)/(c Sqrt[-c (-1 + p) p v^2])

3 - 6/c + 1/(c p - c p^2)
```

What I am trying to do is compare this random variable, when $t=0$, $c = \frac{1}{v^2}$, $v$ approaches $0$, and $c$ thus approaches infinity, with one drawn from the Normal distribution. Under these restrictions, $\mu$ = 0, $\sigma^2 = 4 (1 - p) p$, $\lambda = 3$, and $\kappa = 0$. Thus, it appears we are dealing with the Normal distribution, but that is not necessarily the case (see:[link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154951/non-normal-distributions-with-zero-skewness-and-zero-excess-kurtosis)).

Comment: The distribution is never exactly normal.  So what distance metric would characterize an important difference and what size of difference would be important?  I ask because "how close is close" is a subject matter issue rather than a statistical issue.

Comment: @JimB That is a good question. Suppose I wanted to just inspect visually. For example, if I also set p = 0.5 then variance becomes 1 and a comparison to the Standard Normal distribution would seem appropriate. Could a comparison be setup using Manipulate?

Comment: That's the "I'll know it when I see it" approach.  It's used all the time.  (But it's not necessarily a consistent approach.)  My point is that there's no universally accepted rule.

Comment: The answer from @user120911 below shows that there is an equivalence in distribution in the limit.  Do you also need to know "how close" you are for small values of $v$?

Comment: @JimB That is interesting, but unless you already have that worked out, I would not request it.

Comment: OK.  But I asked because your question is about how the normal distribution compares to your `TransformedDistribution` which (to me) suggests how well does a normal distribution approximate the transformed distribution.  The answer you've got so far is an exact match in the limit.  That's different from how close is the approximation with particular set of parameters.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dist = FullSimplify[TransformedDistribution[2 v S1 + 2 v S2 - v c, {S1 \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[1/2 (c + t), p], S2 \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[1/2 (c - t), 1 - p]}]]
```

The moment generating function of the Dist is

```
MomentGeneratingFunction[Dist, x]

E^(-c v x) (-E^(2 v x) (-1 + p) + p)^((c - t)/2) (1 + (-1 + E^(2 v x)) p)^((c + t)/2)
```

Now let us consider the situation where c = 1/v^2, v-> 0, and t = 0. Under these restrictions, the moment generating function of the Dist is

```
Limit[With[{c = 1/v^2, t = 0},E^(-c v x) (-E^(2 v x) (-1 + p) + p)^((c - t)/2) (1 + (-1 + E^(2 v x)) p)^((c + t)/2)], v -> 0]
```

which simplifies to

```
E^(-2 (-1 + p) p x^2)
```

In comparison, if we examine the Normal Distribution with variance given by -4(-1 + p)p (i.e., the variance of Dist under the stated restrictions), then we notice the moment generating function is

```
MomentGeneratingFunction[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[-4 (-1 + p) p ]],x]

E^(-2 (-1 + p) p x^2)
```

which we notice is equal to the above.

Comment: Did you obtain the mgf from *Mathematica* commands?  If so, would you consider adding those to your answer?

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.